# Adding udev package in Buildroot

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot

I am trying to add `udev` package in Buildroot and have added the following config parameter in the defconfig file:

```ini
./configs/xxx_dev_defconfig:BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_UDEV=y
```

However, I cannot see the above config option is added in the final .config file after doing `make xxx_dev_defconfig`. I noticed the BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_UDEV is set in the previous project in the following locations:

```c
./output/build/buildroot-config/autoconf.h:#define BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_UDEV 1
./output/build/buildroot-config/auto.conf:BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_UDEV=y
```

These look like autogenerated files which are are preset in the current project as well but `BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_UDEV` is missing there. How do I make this `BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_UDEV` config option a part of the auto-generated conf file?

**Edit:**

After doing a bit of faffing around I think I have a temporary solution. In my make menuconfig-> Target packages -> Hardware handling the package option eudev seems to be **not** **select-able**. And it says, " **eudev needs eudev /dev management** ".
[image]

So I looked into the following menuconfig options under System Configuration -> /dev management:
[image]

Inside the /dev management I have to select "Dynamic using devtmpfs + eudev" as below:
[image]

instead of:

[image]

Once I do that then I go back to the following menu option:
[image]

Inside that I go to Hardware handling:
[image]

Now I can see eudev option which I can select:
[image]

Comment: `_HAS_` class of options are usually autoselected. You need to find the one that selects it. E.g., https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/systemd/Config.in#L28.

Comment: How is this related to the `autoconf` tag?

Comment: My ignorance, thought it is something to do with autoconf initially. I have removed that tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the `BR2_PACKAGE_HAS_UDEV` option manually. It's a so-called blind option, it can only be enabled by a `select` statement in one of the user-visible options.

In this case, there are two ways to enable it:

- select `systemd` as the init system (`BR2_INIT_SYSTEMD`);
- select any other init system and select `devtmpfs + eudev` as /dev management (`BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_CREATION_DYNAMIC_EUDEV`).

Comment: that must be the right way to do it, need to test it but yes looks like that would be the way to go. For now I have got an temporary solution which I have pasted on the question itself, hope that is ok?